# Is it possible to implement Rajawali without using gradle?

Tags: android, game-engine

Im trying to use a 3D engine called Rajawali on android, but it doesnt explain how i use it without gradle. So, is it possible to implement Rajawali without gradle, and if it is, how?

https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear to me but I am assuming that you have to add Rajawali to your existing project.
For that in build.gradle file you need to add few lines

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

Now we need to add a line to build.gradle (Module: app) inside the dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

That would integrate Rajawali into your project
If you have further doubts refer the link https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/wiki/AS---Project-and-Dependency-Setup

Comment: I can't use gradle because eclipse doesn't provide me with gradle dependency.

Comment: Please try this link and let me know whether it works for you https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/wiki/Importing-Rajawali-and-RajawaliExamples   If the problem still exists try a manual import of java files, xml files and manifest file to eclipse as a full import of an android studio project to eclipse is not possible. You have to manually do so.